# Script to extract all images from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use the following code to extract all images from the wepage but it gives the error 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'. Can someone tell me what is the problem here?

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'http://pixabay.com'

response = requests.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]


for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$', url)
    with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative 
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens 
            # to be the site variable atm. 
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: For context, since the original question has been updated by someone else, and has changed the original code, the original pattern the user was using was `r'/([\w_-]+.)$'`. This was the original problem. This context will allow the following answer to make more sense:

I went with a pattern like `r'/([\w_.-]+)$'`. The pattern you were using didn't allow the path to contain a `.` except as the last character because `.` outside of `[]` means any character, and you had it right before `$` (the end of the string). So I moved `.` into `[]` which means to allow a literal `.` in the character group.  That allowed the pattern to capture image file names at the end of the URL.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'http://pixabay.com'

response = requests.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_.-]+)$', url)
    with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens
            # to be the site variable atm.
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```